# does such a noun "appropriates" ever exist?

Tags: vocabulary

Your work is all the activities that you do in the course of doing your job and these activities may be seen as **appropriates** as much as **responsibilities**.

I am wondering what the bold part means?

What is more, I never managed to find such a word as a noun, let alone its plural form.

Comment: It's a guess, but an assumed one: Appropriates= appropriate things.

Comment: Are you quoting a text or making this sentence up?

Comment: This is not idiomatic English. Where did you encounter it?

Comment: please provide context, like where did you get the sentence or you read the word. To my knowledge that word as a noun does not exist, unlike *responsibility* (I don't understand why you wrote that bold too).

Comment: @StoneyB I might be wrong, but I believe if we change the sentence a little bit it will be natural - "Your work is all the activities that you do in the course of doing your job and these activities may be seen as much appropriate as responsible."

Comment: @Man_From_India But activities are not responsible: people are responsible **for** activities.

Comment: @StoneyB Ohh, right...It's coming from there :)

Comment: I have answer, but I am not 100% sure about it. Therefore, I will not post it until you answer the above questions, buy editing your answer: 1) are you quoting a text or making it up? 2) Where did you encounter it? 3) Please provide context. For me, #3 means a couple sentences before and/or after the sentence you posted. We answer questions for you as a service. We don't ask for much; in fact, the only thing we want is **more information** so we can provide a better answer.

Comment: No matter what you do with the sentence to make it grammatically correct, it still does not make sense. What is the point of the sentence?

Comment: Thanks. Alas, I cannot remember where I have found such a sentence at all.

Comment: I wish I could provide more information, but I really cannot, or I have no more information-- since I have lost that article or full text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/appropriate?showCookiePolicy=true) and [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/appropriate_1) both list only "appropriateness" as noun derrived from "appropriate" (verb/adjective).

So I'm led to assume that "appropriate" is not a propper noun.